# Using polars is indeed faster than pandas 2 BUT NOT parquet file and either case memory usage is the same as pandas 2

Tags: pandas, python-polars

I am considering moving from pandas to polars. so I am doing some comparison for my big csv reading. The file size of csv is around 600MB.

The message is:

1. even using pandas 2, using pandas 2 without pyarrow( just use normal numpy backend) is faster than pandas 2 with pyarrow, which is surprise to me. I thought pandas 2 is faster ater using pyarrow. It turns out it is even slower. It is disappointing! polars is indeed much faster (3X).
2. However, memory usage of polars is the same as pandas 2 which is 753MB.
3. if I save csv file into parquet file with pyarrow engine. Pandas 2 has same speed as Polars or pandas is even slightly faster which is also very interesting, which make me feel better if I stay with Pandas but just save csv file into parquet file.

I am using dash to develop dashboard with a lot of heatmap plot for a large dateset, so using less memory is critical to me.

Can you advise me how to reduce memory usage for polar read_csv().

Here is the screenshot for my code.

First, read_csv using pandas 2 with pyarrow

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_pyarrow=pd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t',engine='pyarrow')  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 206.8 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 3.45 minutes

df_pyarrow.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3675 entries, 0 to 3674
Columns: 26903 entries, Depth to 2023-03-09 00:06:28
dtypes: float64(26903)
memory usage: 754.3 MB
```

2. using Pandas 2 without pyarrow

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_dts2=pd.read_csv('input\\'+filename,parse_dates=True,sep='\t')  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 121.2 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 2.02 minutes

df_dts2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3675 entries, 0 to 3674
Columns: 26903 entries, Depth to 2023-03-09 00:06:28
dtypes: float64(26903)
memory usage: 754.3 MB
```

3. using Polars

```
import polars as pl
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_dts2=pl.read_csv('input\\'+filename,separator='\t')  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 37.7 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.63 minutes


df_dts2.estimated_size("mb")
763.4694671630859
```

4. using Parquet file

Case: using Pandas 2

```
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_parquet_pyarrow=pd.read_parquet('input\\'+filename_parquet_pyarrow, engine='pyarrow')
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()
timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 13.0 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.22 minutes
```

Case: using Polars

```
import polars as pl
timer_start=timeit.default_timer()
df_polar_parquet=pl.read_parquet('input\\'+filename_parquet_pyarrow)  
timer_end=timeit.default_timer()

timer_minutes=(timer_end-timer_start)/60
timer_seconds=(timer_end-timer_start)

print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_seconds:.1f} seconds')
print(f'Time took to Finish reading file is {timer_minutes:.2f} minutes')

Time took to Finish reading file is 15.7 seconds
Time took to Finish reading file is 0.26 minutes
```

Comment: Did you expect the memory usage to be different?  I certainly wouldn't.  600MB of data with about 20% overhead seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I was told Polar is much more memory efficient than pandas. why they are the same?

Comment: Memory efficiency isn't defined as memory taken from data at rest. Memory efficiency is how much memory is required in order to perform operations. See [here](https://youtu.be/kVy3-gMdViM?si=MaSfsUpJvO1VWdgb&t=1983)

Comment: isolated single commands don't tell the full story, as they mean that Polars' query optimiser doesn't get to shine. Try comparing an entire pipeline, and then you'll see a massive difference

Comment: Right.  If you have 600MB of data, then any process you use is going to require at least 600MB.  There's no magic here.  And if your 600MB is a text file, remember that the 4-byte string "1.3," becomes an 8-byte float in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing any kind of transformation or filtering you will likely see more significant advantages, especially if you were to use `scan_parquet` (which will use the lazy query engine) instead of `read_parquet` (which is eager and will read everything, even if only a few rows are actually needed).

Comment: Thanks alex, can I save this DataFrame after scan_parquet() as a global variable then unpack its values inside different functions? Thanks

Comment: Everything built on top of a LazyFrame will represent a new optimised query plan on the underlying data, so you may need to actively materialise some common piece of it as a DataFrame to cache - at which point you would give up future lazy optimisations on that plan. Now this may not be a bad thing in some cases, so which approach is best will depend heavily on your specific use-case.